# how big is 32 bit as a digits according to agora user id

Tags: flutter, dart

i have read the following doc in agora docs for user uid

> This parameter is a 32-bit unsigned integer. The value range is 1 to
> 232-1

now i am generating random number using the following method

```
int generateRandomUid() {
      var random =  Random();
      return random.nextInt(900000000);
  }
```

now my question does `random.nextInt(900000000)` is suitable with previous doc ? or should i change it ? or how could i always guarantee correct generation

Answer (score 0):

It does depend on the platform, even with Flutter.

On iOS it will go from 0 to UInt.max, all others including Android will be Int.min to Int.max (which I believe is -(2^31 - 1) to (2^31 - 1)).

It makes it pretty awkward to convert, but in swift you could do this:

```swift
// Int -> UInt
UInt(UInt32(bitPattern: Int32(rtcId)))

// UInt -> Int
Int(Int32(bitPattern: UInt32(rtcId)))
```